# Gulp compile SCSS/SASS into separate files

Tags: web-applications, gulp

I'm using the [Yeoman Gulp webapp generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-gulp-webapp) and running into an issue when I build.

I've currently got a project with SASS/SCSS. Right now, they are all compile into the main.css file, but my client wants to have all of the .scss files compile into separate .css files. I see the .scss files compiling into .css files in the .tmp folder, but when I build the project, they dont transfer over to the styles folder in the DIST folder. Do you know how i can change the gulp settings to do this? Basically convert all the .scss files into .css files and include them with the build when i do 'gulp' in the command line?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to:

1. remove comment blocks around `<link>`s to your custom CSS files
2. add this to your `html` task (before the `return` statement):

   ```
   gulp.src('.tmp/styles/*.css')
     .pipe($.minifyCss({compatibility: '*'}))
     .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/styles'));
   ```
3. remove the leading underscore (`_`) from your `.scss` files (`_base.scss` → `base.scss`)
4. `@import` variables, functions etc. into each file individually (when you want to use them), they aren't shared anymore because partials aren't `@import`ed into `main.css`
5. add a `<link>` for every stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying the wildcard css output '*.css'?

For example:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minify = require('gulp-minify-css');

gulp.task('scss', function(){
 gulp.src('.tmp/styles/*.scss')
  .pipe(plumber())
  .pipe(sass())
  .pipe(minify(*.css))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/styles/*.css');
});
```